# Order of 10 in $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ equals order of 10 in $\mathbb{Z}/99\mathbb{Z}$ for p>11 prime

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Why is the order of 10 in $(\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z})^\times$ equal to the order of 10 in $(\mathbb{Z}/99p\mathbb{Z})^\times$ for $p>11$ prime?

Comment: This needs clarification.  the order of 10 mod 99 is 2, no?

Comment: A clue that this cannot be true, is that it would contradict Artin's Conjecture (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artin%27s_conjecture_on_primitive_roots) which predicts that $10$, a squarefree integer, is a primitive root mod $p$ for infinitely many primes $p$.

Comment: Ok, I see the edit.  The 9 you get for free, as 9 always divides $10^k$ - 1.  The 11?  Well...you need an odd number of digits, hence the order would have to be even.  Not sure why that would be...

Comment: if p = 31, the order of 10 is 15.  But 11 does not divide the string of 14 ones.

Comment: Sorry, typo.  Should have said "string of 15 ones". In any case,  the order of 10 mod 99*31 is 30 (and not 15).

Answer (score 2):

Since $p>11$ there is an isomorphism
$\Bbb Z_{99p}^\times\simeq\Bbb Z_9^\times\times\Bbb Z_{11}^\times\times\Bbb Z_p^\times$. Relatively to this isomorphism the subgroup $C$ generated by $10$ decomposes as
$$
\{1\}\times\{\pm1\}\times C^\prime
$$
where $C^\prime$ is the subgroup generated by $10$ in $\Bbb Z_p^\times$ and whose order is the period of $10$ modulo $p$.

Thus the periods coincide for those $p$ such that $10$ has an even period modulo $p$. The comment of lulu indicates that this is not always the case.

Answer (score 0):

It is not. The order of $10$ in $\Bbb Z_{99}^\times$ is $2$ because $10^2-1=99$, but $10^2\not\equiv1\pmod{13}$.

Comment: Sorry, order of 10 in $(\mathbb{Z}/99p\mathbb{Z})^\times$, not in in $(\mathbb{Z}/99\mathbb{Z})^\times$